# Is it possible to nest a jQuery event listener inside an if-statement?

Tags: jquery, if-statement, settimeout, event-listener

I am trying to set up a timeout for users that have logged in on my page. I have a working timeout function that I copied from elsewhere, but there's a slight issue I'm worried about. The page in question is a single page that reloads its content by jQuery/PHP instead of navigating the user to a different URL.

The event listener checks for any user activity, and resets the timeout when that happens. I want the timer to only run when the user is logged in, and once the timeout hits zero it logs the user out. I achieved this by switching a global variable `idleEnabled` between true and false when people login/logout/timeout.

**My issue**: while the *timeout functions* are only available within the event listener if the user is logged in, the *event listener itself* is permanently activated and gets constantly pinged by simply moving the mouse around. I am worried that this might slurp up the client browser capacity.

**What I have**: I've been looking whether I can put an event listener inside `if (idleEnabled == true) { listener here }` but from what I've found this is not possible.  Even if it were, I'm pretty sure a flat if-statement is only run when the script is loaded, but the variable in question will change while the page itself is not reloaded.

**Main question**: Is there any way to do this? Or is this fine and am I worrying over something irrelevant?

**Side question**: I read that it's not preferable to use javascript global variables, but I didn't know any other way to do this. Is it okay to use them like this?

Relevant jQuery code:

```
//create a global timeout handle
var idleTimer = null;
var idleEnabled = false;
var idleWait = 10000; //This is low for testing purposes

//to prevent the timer from disappearing if people refresh the page,
//check if the logout button is on the page when loading the script:
if ($("#logout").length) {window.idleState = true;} 

$('*').on('mousemove keydown scroll', function () { //listen for activity

    if (idleEnabled == true) { //if the timer is enabled...

        clearTimeout(window.idleTimer); //...clear it,

        window.idleTimer = setTimeout(function () { //and reset it, so that...

            $(document).trigger("timeOut"); //...the custom timeout event fires
            window.idleEnabled = false; //...and the timer is disabled

        }, idleWait);

    } 
});

$(".column").on("click", "#login, #logout", {cause: "user"}, validateUser) //Call a validation on login/logout
$(document).on("timeOut", {cause: "timeout"}, validateUser) //Call a validation on timeout

//The function validateUser will set idleEnabled = true on login and idleEnabled = false on logout.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely be able to add the listener inside an `if` branch. On login, you'll need to set it again. Here's how I would do it:

```
var idleTimer = null;
var idleWait = 10000;

// There is probably a better way to check if the user is logged in
function isLoggedIn() {
    return $("#logout").length > 0;
}

function setActivityListener(active) {
    if (active)
        $('*').on('mousemove keydown scroll', activityHandler);
    else
        $('*').off('mousemove keydown scroll');
}

function activityHandler() {
    clearTimeout(idleTimer);
    idleTimer = setTimeout(function () {    
        $(document).trigger("timeOut");
    }, idleWait);
};


if (isLoggedIn()) {
    setActivityListener(true);
}

$(".column").on("click", "#login, #logout", {cause: "user"}, validateUser);
$(document).on("timeOut", {cause: "timeout"}, validateUser);

// On login (in validateUser?)
setActivityListener(true);

// On logout
setActivityListener(false);
```

Comment: ohhhhh of course, you put the if-statement inside a function you can call on login/logout. Thank you so much, I'm putting this in :D